# Is it possible to reliably insert a HTML element at script's location?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm writing a Javascript file which will be a component in a webpage. I'd like it to be simple to use - just reference the script file in your page, and it is there. To that end however there is a complication - where should the HTML go that the Javascript generates? One approach would be to require a placeholder element in the page with a fixed ID or class or something. But that's an extra requirement. It would be better if the HTML was generated at the location that the script is placed (or, at the start of body, if the script is placed in head). Also, for extra customizability, if the fixed ID was found, the HTML would be placed inside that placeholder.

So I'm wondering - how do I detect my script's location in the page? And how do I place HTML there? `document.write()` comes to mind, but that is [documented](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/content-models.html#document.write) as being pretty unreliable. Also it doesn't help if the script is in the head. Not to mention what happens if my script is loaded dynamically via some AJAX call, but I suppose that can be left as an unsupported scenario.

Comment: Sorry but I think this is the wrong approach.  I wrote a "lightweight console" for debugging (86 pure js lines including comments and blank lines) - 1. include the js `<script src="lwcons.js">` in the `<head>` 2. pick a place (or places) on the page for it `<div id="anything"></div>` 3. create it (in .onLoad or .ready or in the page) `var con1 = new Console('anything');` I don't force a fixed ID or class and it doesn't care where the script is. Just a comment since I'm not answering your question.

Comment: Well, that's another (common) approach. I do see the benefits of it. But I was thinking about the ease of usage - just throw in a one-line `<script>` and it's ready! Well, if I can't get it working reliably, I'll probably return to your suggestion as it's the most stable/powerful.

Answer (score 1):

I am doing that with this code...

```
// This is for Firefox only at the moment.
var thisScriptElement = document.currentScript,

// Generic `a` element for exploiting its ability to return `pathname`.
    a = document.createElement('a');


if ( ! thisScriptElement) {
    // Iterate backwards, to look for our script.        
    var scriptElements = document.body.getElementsByTagName('script'),
        i = scriptElements.length;

    while (i--) {
        if ( ! scriptElements[i].src) {
           continue;
        }

        a.href = scriptElements[i].src;
        if (a.pathname.replace(/^.*\//, '') == 'name-of-your-js-code.js') {
            thisScriptElement = scriptElements[i];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, to add your element, it's simple as...

```
currentScript.parentNode.insertBefore(newElement, currentScript);
```

I simply add a `script` element anywhere (and multiple times if necessary) in the `body` element to include it...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="somewhere/name-of-your-js-code.js?"></script>
```

Ensure the code runs as is, **not** in DOM ready or `window`'s `load` event.

Basically, we first check for [`document.currentScript`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.currentScript), which is Firefox only but still useful (if it becomes standardised and/or other browsers implement it, it should be most reliable and fastest).

Then I create a generic `a` element to exploit some of its functionality, such as extracting the *path* portion of the `href`.

I then iterate backwards over the `script` elements (because in parse order the last `script` element should be the currently executing `script`), comparing the filename to what we know ours is called. You may be able to skip this, but I am doing this to be safe.

Comment: I just checked - if the script is in the `<head>`, the `document.body` property returns `null`. So this script would break.

Comment: @Vilx- Yep, you could check the `parentNode` of the script (and modify it to look at all `script` elements, not just in the `body`) to see if it's a child of the `head` element and alter the code accordingly.

Comment: Using an A is not appropriate if the script is in the head, an alternative is to use *document.write* to add a script element with a recognisable attribute value (say type="text/scriptanchor") knowing that it will be placed immediately after the current script element and can go anywhere in the document. If it has no content or *src* it won't hurt anything.

Comment: @RobG: I'm not quite sure I get what you mean, sorry.

Comment: Sorry, thought you were adding the A to the document but you aren't. You're just using it to compare URIs.

Answer (score 1):

*document.write* is very reliable if used as you indicate (a default SharePoint 2010 page uses it 6 times). If placed in the *head*, it will write content to immediately after the body element. The trick is to build a single string of HTML and write it in one go, don't write snippets of half-formed HTML.

An alternative is to use `document.getElementsByTagName('script')` while the document is loading and assume the the last one is the current script element. Then you can look at the parent and if it's the *head*, use the *load* or DOM ready event to add your elements after the body. Otherwise, just add it before or after the script element as appropriate.